# pthread condition signal does not lock mutex

Tags: pthreads, signals, mutex, race-condition

My mutex seems to be unlocked. 
My code looks like this (not actual code) (using pthread):

```
  thread
    {
    int id=...;
    //locked aditional mutex _m2
    mutex_lock(&_m);
    varx=valuex;//irelevant
    print("th%d signaling listener",id);
    cond_signal(&_c);
    print("th%d signaled listener",id);
    mutex_unlock(&_m);
    //unlocked additional mutex _m2
    }

 listener
    {
    tc=0
    mutex_lock(&_m);
    while(tc<threadcount)
        {
        cond_wait(&_c,&_m);
        print("working");
        tc++
        work;
        }
    mutex_unlock(&_m);
    }
```

Normal (predicted )out put:

```
    th0 signaling listener;
    working;
    th0 signaled listener;

    th1 signaling listener;
    working;
    th1 signaled listener;
```

My output:

```
    0 signaling listener;
    working;
    0 signaled listener;

    1 signaling listener;
    1 signaled listener;
```

..so the thread skipped (listener does not execute nor locks _m) to printing output

I've profiled it with helgrind (full) and i have no errors but my app stops at listener because according to him he is waiting for all to finish.

Notes:
listener is joinable.
Additional mutex _m2 does not help.
Thread is detached. I have about 800 detached threads to avoid stack problems, max 50 simultaneous using semaphore to limit thread count.
Code worked for 3-4 threads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pthread_cond_signal()` does not unlock any mutex.  It's not supposed to (no mutex is passed to it).  If at least one thread is waiting on the condition variable signalled, that thread will be scheduled when it can re-acquire the mutex that it passed to `pthread_cond_wait()`.

In your case your listener appears to be waiting on a different condition (`_s`) than the other thread signals (`_c`).

If you fix that problem, you also have the problem that you don't seem to have any shared state between the thread that waits on the condition variable and the thread(s) that signal it.  It looks like your `tc` counter should actually be a shared variable, protected by the `_m` mutex.  Your threads would then do:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&_m);
tc++;
if (tc >= threadcount)
    pthread_cond_signal(&_c);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&_m);
```

and the listener would do:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&_m);
while (tc < threadcount)
    pthread_mutex_wait(&_c, &_m);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&_m);
```

The listener would then only continue once all of the threads have hit the signalling code, which seems to be what you've after.

Alternately you could use `pthread_barrier_wait()`, which appears to be what you're implementing.

Comment: My mistake _s and _c is the same variable i just miss typed it. I kind of fixed my code in the way that I use a queue for my data and lock it both in th, for push, and in listener, for pop. I will look into barrier wait since my code does work but i seem to have some lock fails reported by helgrind(1 to be exact at the end - maybe an error that prevents a mutex unlock). Looked at barrier it doesn't help me.

Comment: I do have a shared variable (x) but since all threads only read from it, i do not not to lock it. listener only checks if all data has been processed and if not processes data in (q-mutexed). th adds further data from known sized, shared variable (x) to (q-mutexed). Code works.

Comment: @LucianMLI: To make correct, non-racy use of pthread condition variables there has to be some kind of writeable shared state involved.

Comment: True. q is writable, shared (mutexed) i forgot about it in the comment.